# Solve $x^{11}+x^8+5\equiv 0\pmod{49}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Solve $x^{11}+x^8+5\pmod{49}$

---

My work

$f(x)=x^{11}+x^8+5$

consider the polynomial congruence $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod {49}$

Prime factorization of $49 = 7^2$

we have $f(x) \equiv 0 \mod 7^2$

Test the value $x\equiv0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ for $x^{11}+x^8+5 \equiv 0\pmod 7$

It works for $x\equiv1$, $x\equiv1\pmod7$ is a solution.

We proceed to lift the solution $\mod 7^2$

$f'(x) = 11x^{10} + 8x^7 +5$, we have $f(1) = 7$ , $f'(x) = 24$

Since $7$ can not divide $f'(1)$, we need to solve $24t \equiv 0 \mod 7$

we get $t \equiv 0 \pmod 5$

and then ..................... ?????

Comment: @RobertIsrael ....  Why??

Comment: And how did you deduce that $t\equiv 0\pmod 5$? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 49\!:\ 5+(1\!+\!7n)^8\!+(1\!+\!7n)^{11}\!\equiv 5 + (1\!+\!56n) + (1\!+\!77n) \equiv 7 - 14 n\equiv 7(1\!-\!2n)$

Thus $\rm\ 49\mid 7\,(1\!-\!2n)\iff 7\mid 1\!-\!2n\iff n\equiv 4\,\ (mod\ 7),\ $ so $\rm\ x \equiv 1+7n\equiv 29\,\ (mod\ 49).$

**Alternatively** $ $ we may compute $\rm\:f(1\!+\!7n)\:$ by Taylor's formula (vs. Binomial Theorem above)

$$\rm mod\ 49\!:\,\ g(n) = f(1\!+\!7n) = g(0) + g'(0)\, n + \cdots\, \equiv\, f(1) + 7\, f'(1)\,n$$

Thus $\rm\ 7\mid f(1)\:\Rightarrow\:49\mid f(1)+7\,f'(1)\,n\!\iff\! 7\mid f(1)/7+f'(1)\,n\!\iff\! n\equiv\, -\dfrac{f(1)/7}{f'(1)}\:\ (mod\ 7)$

So $\rm\,\ mod\ 7\!:\ n \equiv -\dfrac{f(1)/7}{f'(1)} \equiv \dfrac{-1}{11+8}\equiv \dfrac{6}{-2}\equiv -3\equiv 4.\:$ This is equivalent to using *Hensel's Lemma*.

It is instructive to compare the two approaches.

Comment: Very instructive for me, thanks. Why must $x\equiv 1\mod 7$? Is there a nice way to see it besides the exhaustive search?

Comment: It's obvious that $\,1\,$ is a root because $\rm\:f(1) = $ sum of coefficients $\rm\, = 1\!+\!1\!+\!5 \equiv 0\,\ (mod\ 7)$ $\ \ $

Comment: I agree that it's obvious that $1$ is a root mod $7$, but my question is whether it's similarly obvious that there are no other roots mod $7$.

Comment: By little Fermat $\rm\:mod\ 7\!:\ \,x\not\equiv 0\:\Rightarrow\:x^6\equiv 1.\:$ If $\rm\,x\,$ is a root: $\rm\:0 \equiv xf(x) = 5x\!+\!x^9\!+\!x^{12}\!\equiv 5x\!+\!x^3\!+\!1.\:$ So check that from $\pm\{1, 2, 3\}$ only $1$ is a root of this cubic.

Answer (score 2):

If $x = 1 + 7 t$ for an integer $t$, then $x^{11} \equiv 1 + 11 (7 t) \mod 49$, 
$x^8 \equiv 1 + 8 (7 t) \mod 49$, and so $f(x) \equiv 7 + 19 (7t) \mod 49$.
Thus you want $1 + 19 t \equiv 0 \mod 7$, ...

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) ?

First, let us find a solution modulo $\,7\,$ of $\,f(x)=x^{11}+x^8+5\pmod 7\,$.
Clearly, $\,r=1\,$ is a root. Now, define

$$t:=-\frac{f(1)}{7}f'(1)^{-1}=-(11+8)^{-1}=(-19)^{-1}=30^{-1}=18\pmod{49}\Longrightarrow $$

$$s:=1+18\cdot 7=127=29\pmod{49}\,\,\,\text{is a root of}\,\,\,f(x)\pmod{49}$$

What is cool in this method is that it allows you find roots modulo $\,7^2\,,\,7^3\,\ldots\,,\,7^k\,$ , for any $\,k\in\Bbb N\,$ , as long as you have one **simple** root modulo $\,7\,$ (why does it have to be "simple"?)

Comment: havent seen it before but it looks so awesome

Comment: @Pau Note that the inverse need only be computed mod $7$, not mod $49,\ $ (see my answer).